# intern.js and Browserstack

Tags: intern, browserstack

Intern.js is a great testrunner but it only appears to work with SauceLabs. My company already uses BrowserStack and are very happy with it. I was wondering if anyone has been able to integrate Intern.js with BrowserStack and if so how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use BrowserStack with the following Intern configuration for Intern 1:

```js
define({
  capabilities: {
    'browserstack.user': 'your-username',
    'browserstack.key': 'your-access-key'
  },
  webdriver: {
    host: 'hub.browserstack.com'
  },
  useSauceConnect: false
});
```

or this configuration for Intern 2:

```js
define({
  tunnel: 'BrowserStackTunnel',
  tunnelOptions: {
    username: 'your-username', // or use env var BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME
    accessKey: 'your-access-key' // or use env var BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY
  }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you update this response for Intern 2?  (I haven't been able to get BrowserStack to work yet but I see that other people have, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629522/working-with-intern-js-and-browserstack-access-the-remote-browser-environment

Answer (score 1):

These settings work for me:

```
tunnel: 'BrowserStackTunnel',
webdriver: {
    username: 'your-useranme',
    accessKey: 'your-access-key',
},
```